# R: get the column names where rowSum is equal to a value

Tags: r, dataframe, rowsum

I have a dataframe with multiple columns where its `rowSums` is either `1` either `0.9`. 
If one column is `0.5`, than another one has to be `0.5`. If a column is `0.3`, then other two have to have the same value.

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(0, 0, 0.3, 0.5, 0, 0.3, 0.5), B = c(0, 0, 0.3, 0.5, 0, 0.3, 0.5), 
C = c(1, 1, 0.3, 0, 1, 0.3, 0))
```

What I need in the end is another column (`result`) that has the column names where the values > 0.

```
> df
    A   B   C result
1 0.0 0.0 1.0      C
2 0.0 0.0 1.0      C
3 0.3 0.3 0.3  A-B-C
4 0.5 0.5 0.0    A-B
5 0.0 0.0 1.0      C
6 0.3 0.3 0.3  A-B-C
7 0.5 0.5 0.0    A-B
```

Thanks!

Comment: A bit faster base base R option could be `indx <- which(df > 0, arr.ind = TRUE) ; df$result <- tapply(names(df)[indx[, "col"]], indx[, "row"], toString)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
df$result <- apply(df, 1, function(x) paste(names(df)[x > 0], collapse = "-"))

df
    A   B   C result
1 0.0 0.0 1.0      C
2 0.0 0.0 1.0      C
3 0.3 0.3 0.3  A-B-C
4 0.5 0.5 0.0    A-B
5 0.0 0.0 1.0      C
6 0.3 0.3 0.3  A-B-C
7 0.5 0.5 0.0    A-B
```

Answer (score 1):

`library(tidyverse)`

```
df %>% 
mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
pivot_longer(-id, names_to = "cd", values_to = "vals") %>% 
filter(vals > 0) %>% 
group_by(id) %>% 
summarise(new_val = paste(cd, collapse = "-")) %>% 
ungroup() %>% 
cbind(df, .)
```